# Trying to access MySQL with perl script

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbd

Learning to use Perl DBI, with MySql.

Need to do the equivalent of this command

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

In a Perl Script.

Here is the script I am using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10; # for say() function
use DBI;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:youtube_data_tmp:localhost";
my $username = "root";
my $password = '';

say "Perl MySQL INSERT Demo";

my %attr = (PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr);
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::mysql module)
```

When I try to download DBD::mysql from CPAN I keep getting this error:

> The bundle file "/Users/Zhiang/.cpan/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm" may be a broken
>   bundlefile. It seems not to contain any bundle definition.
>   Please check the file and if it is bogus, please delete it.
>   Sorry for the inconvenience.

I am really lost, and have know idea where to go from here. Is this a Perl script problem or an issue with the module ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file `/Users/Zhiang/.cpan/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm` as the error message suggests?

Comment: "When I try to download DBD::mysql from CPAN" — How are you doing this?

Comment: @simbabque should i just delete the mysql.pm, or the whole ".cpan/Bundle/DBD" and reinstall DBD ?

Comment: @Quentin going on CPAN via the shell, `get DBD::mysql`

Comment: If you had used `get DBD::mysql` then `cpan` would have downloaded and untarred `DBD-mysql.4.041.tar.gz` into a temporary directory. Whatever you did next is wrong. What gave you the idea to mess with `Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm`? You shouldn't be touching anything in that directory except perhaps `Makefile.PL`. It's best not to guess when installing stuff.

Comment: @Borodin , thats literally all I did, but that was after I had all those errors from the script, I only used the `get DBD::mysql` at CPAN, just in case, and Im still getting the bundle errors. I have NOT messed with the `Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm` at all.

Comment: So exactly what do you do to get `The bundle file "/Users/Zhiang/.cpan/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm" may be a broken bundlefile`?

Comment: Have you used `use lib` in your program, or set the `PERLLIB` or `PERL5LIB` environment variables? There's no way an ordinary Perl program will go searching through the private `.cpan` directory tree without being told to.

Comment: @Borodin I used the `use lib` function, didnt work, got the same error.  Heck stil getting this error `install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC`. So it looks like a a broken bundle file, the question i have for you is, how to fix a broken bundle file, when redownloading download from CPAN doesnt work.

Comment: It sounds very much like you have never installed `DBD::mysql`. I still want to know what you were doing to get a message about `.cpan/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm`. Nothing should be looking in there.

Comment: I should be in bed -- it's 3:30am. Write a new question and include the code of your Perl program and the log that shows you running `cpan` and `get DBD::mysql` to create the *broken bundlefile* message. I'll take a look in the morning.

Comment: @Borodin  ok I deleted `/Users/Zhiang/.cpan/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm`, still not working. Then tried `get  DBD::mysql`, worked, `make DBD::mysql` worked, ` test DBD::mysql` get this error  `#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 15.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.'` , also install get the same error.